# What do you call an unintentional target?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

What do you call a target that is not necessarily intentional? For example, if a missile hits a hospital, what do you call it? If I said, 'Targets included a hospital', it would suggest that the military did it on purpose. What is a broader synonym for 'target'?

Answer (score 1):

[Collateral damage,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collateral%20damage)

> injury inflicted on something other than an intended target

Comment: What do you call a single object that was hit (whether intentionally or not)?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev There is no upper or lower limit aside from what is inherent to the particular weapon.

Comment: 'Collateral damage' is NOT what I'm looking for. Please reread the question